# Using wrapper Class in Lightning:Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, wrapper-class, lightning-datatable

I am trying to set the data of the Lightning:Datatable from the wrapper class in server-side Controller.

```
    public class AccountWrapper{       
        @AuraEnabled public Account acct {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public boolean isSelected {get;set;}        
        @AuraEnabled public String errorMsg {get;set;}

        public AccountWrapper (Account acc, boolean b, String msg){
            acct = acc;  
            isSelected = b; 
            errorMsg = msg;
        }  
    }
```

When I am setting the value of the attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="data" type="List"/>
```

as :- `component.set("v.data", response.getReturnValue().lstAcctWrapper);`

But the problem is how we can distinguish the value in the column as rows coming blank.

```
<lightning:datatable
    keyField="id"
    data="{! v.data }"
    columns="{! v.columns }"
    hideCheckboxColumn="false"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the field definiation with data to make it work

```
cmp.set("v.columns", response.getReturnValue().ldwList);
cmp.set("v.data", response.getReturnValue().sobList);
cmp.set("v.fieldsList", response.getReturnValue().fieldsList);
```

and then need to use same in DataTable as well

```
<lightning:datatable
    columns="{! v.columns }"
    data="{! v.data }"
    keyField="{! v.keyField }"
    showRowNumberColumn="true"
```

You can find working example on my blog here: [Lightning Data Table With Lazy Loading](https://newstechnologystuff.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/lightning-data-table-with-lazy-loading/)